# Vs Code Problem : The value of the local variable item is not used

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, local-variables

As I mentioned on the subject, I am facing the warning "The value of the local variable [item] is not used"

I clearly used the variable on my coding but it shows me that type of error. It will be highly appreciated if you can advise me on this.

```
public int pop() {
        int item;
        while(stack1 != null){
            System.out.println("stack1  "+stack1.data);
            stack1 = stack1.next;
        }
        MyQueue dummy = new MyQueue(0);
        if(stack2 == null){
            while(stack1 != null){
                stack2 = stack1;
                stack1 = stack1.next;
                dummy.next = stack2;
                System.out.println(dummy.next.data+"<- dummy node ");
            }
            item = dummy.next.data;
            dummy.next = dummy.next.next;
            }
        dummy.next = stack2;
        item = dummy.next.data;
        dummy.next = dummy.next.next;
        return stack2.data;
        }
```

Comment: You are <em>setting</em> item but not using the value for anything like printing, etc

Comment: "Used" means using it's *value*. Assigning to a variable is not "using" it. If you only ever assign a value to a variable, but never use that value, what's the point of assigning it in the first place? The compiler is being helpful, telling you that your code is pointless.

Comment: What if iam using it as a temporary variable ?